# angular2 alpha.37 has a breaking change affecting jspm.io and page load

Tags: typescript, atom-editor, angular

I have been using the Angular2 load scripts, below, for many versions in index.html, and they load a simple test app.  When the alpha number changes from 36 to 37, this no longer works. Loading appears, but the component aimed at this link no longer loads.

```
<res-app><h1>Loading . . .</h1></res-app>

<!-- ES6-related imports -->
<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
<!-- links to angular2 compiler and router. -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.36/angular2.dev.js"> </script> <!--Must be after the 2 es6 above -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.36/router.dev.js"></script>
<!--System loads app.ts / app.js -->
<script>System.import('app').catch(console.log.bind(console));</script>
```

I'm using atom-typescript in the Atom editor. I get the Console error

```
Error loading "app" at https://registry.jspm.io/app.js
Not Found: https://registry.jspm.io/app.js
```

I did some searches, tried several things, but got no joy.
What is the new way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work with alpha.37:

```
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
 <script>
        System.config({
            baseURL: '/js',
            defaultJSExtensions: true
        });
 </script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.37/angular2.min.js"></script>
```

And then at the bottom of the file:

```
 <script>
    System.import('app');
</script>
```

In my example, I have all my JavaScript in a folder `/js`, which is why I set the `baseURL` property.

I derived this from a Plunker example I found inside the Angular 2 docs:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bRs0SX2OTQiJzqvjgl8P?p=preview

Comment: Yes, so your 4th line becomes - baseURL: '/projectFileName',  - and it works. I am using a different script source for alpha.37, and it still works.  Thanks.